# How do you fix this lighting bug when using cycles baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm doing cycles baking for the backrooms and theres weird shadow seams on the walls. I cycles baked with default settings and used smart uv project for the uv [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you call "weird shadow seams"?

Comment: the shadow seam on the wall on the left